# "Request method 'POST' not supported" when I try to upload file (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I want to make file upload but get this error.

There is my Controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/uploadImage")
public String uploadImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){

    if(!file.isEmpty()){
        try {
            byte[] imageData = file.getBytes();

            imageService.uploadImage(imageData);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return "redirect:/user/image";
}
```

There is my jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/uploadImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And there is my CommonsMultipartResolver bean in AppConfig:

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000);

    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: Is there any `@RequestMapping` annotation on your Controller? Because from what I see you are trying to send request to `/user/uploadImage`, while POST method is exposed on `/uploadImage`.

Comment: @Anastasia, yes I have @RequestMapping("/user")

Comment: `/user/image` is a GetMapping right?

Comment: @DirkDeyne , yes

Comment: Hmm, strange... I think your code should work... Here is a working [demo](https://gist.github.com/dirkdeyne/1820b99e121b6e64b8b835bb699a1981)

Comment: @DirkDeyne I resolved problem, the issue was with ?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}. But thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I use Spring Security and I needed to add ?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token} to the end of action in jsp, there is some code now.

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/uploadImage?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form:form>
```